# How do I install OpenCV for PHP?

Tags: php, linux, opencv

I'm trying to install OpenCV for PHP but it doesn't work.
https://github.com/mgdm/OpenCV-for-PHP
I did the following

installed OpenCV

> $ sudo aptitude install libcv2.1

tried to install opencv for php

> $ sudo phpize && ./configure && make && make install

tried to uses it and I got an error

> $ php examples/test_convert.php

`php: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/php5/20090626/opencv.so: undefined symbol: cvSetErrMode`

I thought the OpenCV for PHP needs the OpenCV libs address,

> $ ldd /usr/lib/php5/20090626/opencv.so
>   linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff45de2000)
>   libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd2d74c3000)
>   /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd2d7a8a000)

so I tried this

> $ phpize
>   $ ./configure
>   edit Makefile
>   < OPENCV_SHARED_LIBADD =
>   > OPENCV_SHARED_LIBADD = /usr/lib/libcv.so.2.1
>   $ make
>   $ sudo make install

and it still doesnt work.
I'm using Ubuntu11.04.
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.xarg.org/project/php-facedetect/ is a very good tutorial to install OpenCV on linux machine, if you know a little about PHP & Apache Web Server this tutorial will help you a lot

Regrads

Umair Iqbal

Comment: thank you for your help! what I want to do with the opencv is not facedetect but a kind of template matching. I use it to solve a pc game(minesweeper) and need to detect the template on the image. I think I need the cvMatchTemplate function.

Comment: the topic of your question is how to install opencv for php and this tutorial shows how to do it :) once installed you can use any function of the library

Answer (score 1):

- You can try this https://github.com/hihozhou/php-opencv
- Supporting the latest php7+ and opencv3.3+
- Doc:http://phpopencv.org/docs
- In addition to the basic image processing, it also implements face detection and face recognition

e.g:

```
use CV\Face\LBPHFaceRecognizer;
//use ...;

$src = imread('facePic.jpg');
$gray = cvtColor($src, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
equalizeHist($gray, $gray);
$faceRecognizer =                 LBPHFaceRecognizer::create();
/* ... */ //get $images and $labels for train
$faceRecognizer->train($images, $labels);//How to get $image and $labels, see the document
/* ... */ //Face detection using CascadeClassifier
$faceLabel = $faceRecognizer->predict($gray);
/* ... */ //draw face and name
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone needs I've improved a bit the library:
https://github.com/ProGM/OpenCV-for-PHP

I fixed compilation for php5.4 and added a solution for your issue. Follow the installation guide:
https://github.com/ProGM/OpenCV-for-PHP/wiki/Installation-guide

Regards.