# Opencv for php wrapping issue

Tags: php, c++, opencv

I can successfully install opencv for php in linux as of [How do I install OpenCV for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360527/how-do-i-install-opencv-for-php) with extension available at https://github.com/mgdm/OpenCV-for-PHP/tree/master. But i need same in windows,please help how can i wrap it in php in windows,i'm, new to windows.How can i get start to do same?
Note: I don't want simply wrapping for face detect as i know.I just need it to be more of sift,surf implemantation.

Comment: rather do not use a 4 year old, unmaintained wrapper around the deprecated c-api. the format of the haarcascades has changed, it won't be able to read the current ones, and no, you can't do SIFT via the c-api.

Comment: @berak Then, how can i use opencv with php in windows for surf/sift implemantaion, pls suggest any advice or source.Its very important project for me.

Comment: sorry, no idea, just trying to warn you that this one won't fly.